# How can I call methods within a nested class using new()?

Tags: c++, pointers, nested, instance

Right now, I have a nested class as so:

```
class Outer{

public:
    class Inner{

    public:
        void display(){
             cout << "You are in inner class" << endl;
        }
     };
     void display(){
         cout << "You are in outer class" << endl;
     }
};
```

I have to create an instance of each class `Outer` and `Inner` so I can invoke each of their `display()` methods. I have to use `new` in order to invoke them as part of my requirement. I can invoke the `Outer` class fine and point to its method as so:

```
Outer *pOuter = new Outer();
pOuter->display();
```

But, I'm having troubles doing the same to the `Inner` class. I've tried:

```
 Outer:Inner *pInner = new Outer:Inner();
 pInner->display();
```

but, that doesn't work. So I'm wondering what I can do to invoke the inner method while using `new`?

Comment: The fully qualified name of `Inner` is `Outer::Inner`. And `pOuter:Inner` is just silly.

Comment: _that doesn't work_ that are to many details.

Comment: Just a little point about terminology: Java has outer and inner classes, with a particular meaning that C++ does not support. As in the title, the best term in C++ is **nested class**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fully qualified path:

```
Outer::Inner* p = new Outer::Inner;
p->display();
delete p;
```

Without pointers:

```
Outer::Inner o;
o.display();
```

Or mark the function `static` and call as:

```
Outer::Inner::display();
```

That being said, as-is this is better suited for a (`Outer`) namespace instead of a class.